# Acumatica 6.10.0010: ARSalesPriceMaint.CalculateSalesPrice not working from Extension BLC

Tags: acumatica

My Acumatica upgrade to 6.10.0010 is giving me an error when ARSalesPriceMaint.CalculateSalesPrice is called from an Extension class.

I cannot tell if the Singleton approach to ARSalesPriceMaint leads to this error when called thru an Extension class such as SOOrderEntry, ARCashSaleEntry, others:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of 
the collection.
Parameter name: index

   at   
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument 
argument, ExceptionResource resource)
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, 
    IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at 
    PX.Data.PXCache.AlteredDescriptor..ctor(PXEventSubscriberAttribute[] 
    attributes, HashSet`1 fields, _CacheAttachedDelegate method, Type 
    cacheType)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.b(Type A_0)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.CreateInstance(Type graphType, String prefix)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.CreateInstance(Type graphType)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.CreateInstance[Graph]()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at PX.Objects.AR.ARSalesPriceMaint.get_SingleARSalesPriceMaint()
   at PX.Objects.AR.ARSalesPriceMaint.CalculateSalesPrice(PXCache sender, String custPriceClass, Nullable`1 customerID, Nullable`1 inventoryID, CurrencyInfo currencyinfo, String UOM, Nullable`1 quantity, DateTime date, Nullable`1 currentUnitPrice)
```

...

I am using VS2013 and hope to upgrade to VS2015 soon.

Has anyone encountered this error type and know how to work around?
Thank you.

Comment: I was able to create a separate public class that has the price calc methods of SalesPriceMaint, and that handles the SOLine pretty well (for now) without error.  However, I am no longer getting SOLineSplits nor INitemPlan created upon Save of the SOOrder (and hence, CreateShipment finds nothing to do). Copy/Paste of an older completed SO Order also lacks splits/planIds. Where can I look in V6.1 to discover how/when SOLineSplit recs are created? Earlier this month, testing of V6.0 (.1596) did not show this behavior.

Comment: EDIT:  I updated to VS2015, recompiled under TargetFramework 4.6.1 and C#6, but the CalculateSalesPrice error remains.

Comment: When copying ARSalesPriceMaint into my own public class for debugging into the code, the Singleton approach used works just fine.  The "index out of range" error observed can be solved by commenting out the following DAC Overrides block of code just after the Singleton declare:

Comment: [PXString(30, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
        [PXDefault(typeof(ARSalesPriceFilter.priceCode), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Price Code", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
        [PXPriceCodeSelector(typeof(ARSalesPrice.priceCode), typeof(ARSalesPrice.priceCode), typeof(ARSalesPrice.description),
            ValidateValue = false, DescriptionField = typeof(ARSalesPrice.description))]
        public virtual void ARSalesPrice_PriceCode_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }

Comment: But again, downstream from successfully adding the SOLine to the Sales Order Entry, there are no SOLineSplit/INItemPlan recs upon Save and hence, the CreateShipment action finds nothing planned...

Answer (score 0):

This upgrade error type ended up being from my customization code, specifically from an older DAC extension of ARSalesPrice for a custom field called PriceCode (note the lack of the 'usr' prefix).  A secondary problem for lack of SOShipLineSplits was related to an older Cst_SOLine class I had from ACE customization. By moving its 3 custom fields into a new CacheExtension class, the problem was resolved.